# Split list of text in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, python-3.6

I have pandas dataframe consist of list of text, i want to split the text by ,

```
df['c1']=['this is text one','this is text two','this is text three']
```

I tried this

```
new = df["c1"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)
```

but it me Nan on new variable

expected output

```
c1='this is text one'
c1='this is text two'
c1='this is text three'
```

other output is ok as long as it split the text in the list. Thank you for your help
Full code

```
import pandas as pd
data={"C1":[["this is text one","this is text two","this is text three"]]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

Comment: can i see the full code?

Comment: I cannot share the full code, but the flow is looks like this
```
import pandas as pd
data={"C1":[["this is text one","this is text two","this is text three"]]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: i want to know the structure of the df array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need pandas to split an array you can use for loop

here is what you need

```
for i in df['C1']:
    for each in i:
        print(each) #outputs each element in the array
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.concatenate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and call the dataframe constructor (*since you already have a list of strings*):

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df1.C1),columns=['C1'])
#or pd.DataFrame(df1.C1.values.tolist()).T
```

---

```
                   C1
0    this is text one
1    this is text two
2  this is text three
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing - you say you already have a list of texts, so why do you want to split it? If what you mean is rather that you have a dataframe with strings that mush be split by commas, you could do something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['c1']=['this is the first text, which has some commas, in it',
          'this is text two, which also has commas']

df['lists'] = df['c1'].apply(lambda txt: txt.split(','))

df.head()
```

Running `df['lists'][0]` then gives `['this is the first text', ' which has some commas', ' in it']`

Comment: This code give me an error.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: It won't if you run both pieces of code. If you run the second part twice it will, of if you use the second part with the bit you posted.

Comment: Ok, i understand what you mean, but in my problem the df['c1'] is consists of list of list not just list. Thank you

Comment: Alright - but then what are you looking or? If it is already a list of lists, why are you trying to split it? Do you want a list of lists of lists?